# Continuous functions in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $A ⊂ X$, $f: A \rightarrow Y$ continuous and $Y$ a Hausdorff space.

Prove that *if* $f$ can be extended to a continuous function $g: \overline{A} \rightarrow Y$, then $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

I must show that $g$ is uniquely determined by $f$. When $A$ is closed, the result is immediate. If $A$ is not closed, then I assumed absurdly that this is not true, but this way the test has turned out to be cumbersome, therefore, I have not been able to reach a result.
So I would like to know some other way to face this problem.

Definition 1: Let $(X, \tau)$ and $(Y, \upsilon)$ be topological spaces. A function $f: X \to Y$ is said to be
continuous if for each open subset $V$ of $Y$, the set $f^{-1}[V]$ is an open subset of $X$.

Definition 2: A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called a Hausdorff space if for each pair $x$, $y$ of points other than $X$, there are neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of $x$ and $y$, respectively, that are disjoint.

Comment: In what way cumbersome? It sounds like it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one key point here, the fact that $Y$ is Hausdorff. This means that limits in $Y$ are unique. That is, if $\{y_n\}_n$ sequence in $Y$ such that $y_n\to y$ and $y_n\to y'$ as $n\to\infty$, then $y=y'$.

Now suppose that $g$ is a continuous extension of $f$. Assuming continuity is very important (otherwise the result is not true). We'll show that $g$ is unique.

To see this take $x\in\overline{A}$. There exists $\{x_n\}_n$ sequence in $A$ such that $x_n\to x$. Since $g$ is continuous,
\begin{equation}
g(x)= \lim_{n\to\infty} g(x_n)= \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n),
\end{equation}
where the last equality holds because $g|_A= f$. As a result, by the uniqueness of limits, $g(x)$ is uniquely determined by $f$.

Comment: Note that  it is possible that the closure of a set is not always the set of limits of convergent *sequences* in the set.

Comment: I don't understand why $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  
 $exists in  $A$ such that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$

Comment: By definition of $\overline{A}$ which is the smallest closed set containing $A$. If you let $F=\{x\in X; \exists\{x_n\}_n\subset A: x_n\to x\}$ then you can show that $A\subset F$ and $F$ is closed thus, $\overline{A}\subset F$.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose $g_1, g_2$ are two such continuous extensions. Suppose there is a point $x \in \overline{A}$ such that $g_1(x) \neq g_2(x)$. Using the Hausdorff condition, fix disjoint open neighbourhoods $V_1, V_2$ of $g_1(x)$ and $g_2(x)$ respectively.

Since $g_1, g_2$ are continuous at $x$, there exist open neighbourhoods $U_1, U_2$ of $x$ such that $U_i \subseteq g_i^{-1}(V_i)$. Consider the open neighbourhood $U = U_1 \cap U_2$ of $x$. Since $x \in \overline{A}$, there must be a point $y \in A \cap U$. Then $g_1(y) = g_2(y)$ and
$$y \in U_i \subseteq g_i^{-1}(V_i) \implies g_i(y) \in V_i.$$
But then $g_1(y) = g_2(y) \in V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand uhy $g_{1} (y) = g_{2} (y)$?

Comment: @JhöśëElijäh Because $y \in A$, and $g_1$ and $g_2$ are extensions of the same function on $A$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you